# How to send the IAP Auth token to Oauth 2 from backend when it is redirecting from backend ( backend is in flask)?

Tags: reactjs, api, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

frontend - react ,
Backend - flask,
I have deployed my app on appengine (GCP) now for authentication, I turned on IAP.
Frontend and backend runs on different url ( for example - abc.appspot.com for frontend and bcd.appspot.com for backend)
For the frontend to connect to this Oauth, i added **credentials: true**( since it's a cross orgin) so frontend url is authenticated and sends the request to backend through api.
Now backend to get authenticated sends the request to Oauth which fails since auth token is not sent which I observed in network upon inspection.
I do not know how to add this kind of credentials:true for backedn so that BE also get authenticated.
Also BE directly redirects to Oauth
ie accounts.google.com/o/oauth/v2/auth?clientid="whateveritis"

Ps : if I load seperately in browseer
bcd.appspot.com BE in seperate tab and then load fronend (app) .. The app completely works
This is coz backend is already authenticated so when the backedn redirects to Oauth, it says yes go ahead!!!!

How to send browser IAP AUTH TOKEN TO BACKEND which sends to Oauth to get authenticated